# Separate ConnectionStrings and mailSettings from web.config? Possible?

Tags: web-config, connection-string

Is it possible to separate ConnectionStrings and mailSettings from web.config?

Devel environment has different IP addresses for connectionstrings and smtp mails because of development and testing. We dont want to do tests and devel using live machines and live IP addresses.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the answer on MSDN:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/> 
</configuration>
```

With file `connections.config` containing

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="name" connectionString="conn_string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="name2" connectionString="conn_string2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: @Bobi I suppose it would allow for preparing a deployment where the dev/test connection string files are copied over only during a dev/int release, to more easily switch between the settings across the environments. Different approach to doing a transform file I suppose.