# Using a separate file to maintain the connection string for entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I have my connection string currently in my web.config file.

Is it possible to place it in a separate file and point entity framework to it.

Comment: appsettings has a [file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) attribute that can point to another file. It is recommended that this file also has a `.config` extension for security.

Comment: Sorry but the connection string for entity framework is stored under connection string element and not the app config. but your solution pointed me to search for something similar there and i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582970/separate-connectionstrings-and-mailsettings-from-web-config-possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate ConnectionStrings and mailSettings from web.config? Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582970/separate-connectionstrings-and-mailsettings-from-web-config-possible)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the answer here [Separate ConnectionStrings and mailSettings from web.config? Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582970/separate-connectionstrings-and-mailsettings-from-web-config-possible):

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/> 
</configuration>
```

With file `connections.config` containing

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="name" connectionString="conn_string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="name2" connectionString="conn_string2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question. You can put the connection strings in a separate config file using configSource but DONT expect the EF designer to work happily with it.

Every time to go to edit the edmx and 'Update from Database' it will ask for a new connection string and then always want to save it back to the web.config. Not ideal and for me not workable. This is the case in EF6 and previous.

Comment: With Database first design, yeah you're right, but code first won't edit the web.config, which is the most actual and correct approach any project should have.

Comment: Don't assume that "Code First" is always going to be the best way forward with new EF projects, even "green field". Code First's migration model for database updates has been such a massive headache for me in the past that I've preferred the Database First approach even when I have carte blanche on data design. You make your DB change, script it so you can make the same change to other environments, then update the EDMX and start using the updated domain layer.

Comment: Of course, if you're going to adopt a DB-First approach, you're pretty much stuck with EF6, as EF7/Core 1.0 is dumping the Model Designer.

Comment: Just because the EDMX has gone doesn't necessarily mean your stuck with EF6. I'm sure there's a reverse engineer/ poco generator for EF7 for the numerous enterprise devs that develop database first.