# How to pass a EF DB First connection string via constructor instead put in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm developing a DataBase First EF application and everything is working great with the auto-generated code and app.config sections. But when I try to remove the connection string of the app.config and put it as parameter on the DbContext constructor I cannot get it to work.

The connection string in the app.config:

```
  <add name="EntityContext" 
       connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelHistory.csdl|res://*/ModelHistory.ssdl|res://*/ModelHistory.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=XXXXX;PASSWORD=xxxxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXXX&quot;" 
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And im trying to pass it via constructor:

```
public EntityContext() : base(GetConnectionString()) { }

private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return metadata=res://*/ModelHistory.csdl|res://*/ModelHistory.ssdl|res://*/ModelHistory.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=XXXXX;PASSWORD=xxxxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXXX&quot;" 
}
```

But it  throws the error:

> Additional information: Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception.

Comment: If you are using database-first, your only real choice to change the connection string is using the app.config file. Don't make your own connection context class, which is made for you.

Comment: So why do you want to take the connection string out of the config file to begin with?

Comment: @gunr2171 But if the requirement is not show the connection string via app.config and set it hardcode, i dont have any option?

Comment: Is your application expecting to change connection strings often while it's running?

Comment: @gunr2171 for security reasons, actually its encrypted in the registry

Comment: AFAIK, DB-first will only let you get the connection string from the config file, or a [separate, unencrypted file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153666/using-a-separate-file-to-maintain-the-connection-string-for-entity-framework). If you want to pass in the connection string manually, you need to go code-first.

Comment: @gunr2171 hum, thats bad

Comment: Argh! this is bad indeed, has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

We need to move the connection string from app.config file to the code. This can be done in context.cs file.
In the constructor you need to specify the connection string
In your connection string you need to replace Replace quote " with '(single quote)

```c#
public partial class ProducerCentralEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ProducerCentralEntities()
      : base(@"metadata = res://*/TestProj.csdl|res://*/TestProj.ssdl|res://*/TestProj.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';data source=serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;application name=EntityFramework';")
        {
        }
      }
```

Note:
1) You should have complete connection string
2) Replace quote " with '

Comment: and not use &quot; in the passed connection string.  It should be a single ' .