# Database-First Entity Framework with SQL Server credentials?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Does anyone know of any way in which a database-first Entity Framework dbcontext can be implemented using SQLCredential? (you cannot pass a new `SqlConnection` with an allowable connection string - they are rejected).
Code-first will allow this, but not database-first. Basically, I can't create a database-first connection string that allows a new `SqlConnection` to instantiate correctly nor do I have decrypted credentials available to me. 
I am completely open to ideas.

Sample (model exists in dll, as database-first):

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string connStr, SqlCredential creds)
        : base(new SqlConnection(connStr, creds), true)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Must be a mistake in the connection string. If you're authorized for the database schema in any way you can create a model from the database.

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue. The model is created. I'm trying to use a sqlcredential with a database-first connection string.  Since the meta element is not supported in a standard SqlConnection, I'm not able to do this with a database first dbcontext model (altering the constructor to pass sqlconnection, true)

Comment: The word "implement" a context is confusing. I guess you mean "initialize". If so, this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26065626/861716

Comment: That answer is completely lame.To move your connection string out of the config doesn't resolve the issue of using a sql credential.  I do not have unencrypted credentials, only a sql credential from a blob. This is not a duplicate, as the other answer has nothing to do with sql credential.

Comment: It's about the metadata, not the constructor. Maybe you should tell more exactly what you do and which errors you get so comments can be more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: No, you can't. Because entity framework doesn't use sqlclient namespace internally and inherits from Common instead.
The only way to do it is a string replace method in the connection string itself.