# Centralized connection string. What are common practices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I’m looking for a way of centrally locating a couple connection strings. Our team has a bunch of projects mostly console applications but also a couple Web API and Websites. Of course that number continues to grow especially in the console app and Web API. We have the need to now change the DB server and username/password on all of them. We have no choice but to do it manually on every one of them right now but going forward we would like to come up with a central location so that we could just change a file or location once and all of our apps would pick up the settings from there.

I’ve been doing some searching and the so far I see suggestions of using and external config file, use the machine.config, or maybe a web service to get the information.

Using an external file doesn’t seem that it would help a whole lot because if a change is needed you still have to change the file on all the apps even though it’s external.

In theory the machine.config seems to be logical to me right now. You just put the connection information at the machine level and any app, site, or Web API should be able to pick it up. However, I see a lot of discussions where people are discouraging that practice. In addition I’m trying to get my code to pull the connection information from the machine.config but I haven’t been able to get it to work at the moment.

So, what are some suggestions? Anyone with real world pros/cons on using the machine.config, external file or maybe a webservice to store connection string information?

Comment: [This is why Best Practice questions stink](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Answer (score 3):

A simplest way of doing it is to use keep your configuration file in a single project and add that configuration file to other projects as "[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx)".

You can also just keep the connection strings [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15154456/881798) from the application configuration in separate configuration file. and use the reference of the connection string in separate configuration files. This is more concrete solution.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/> 
</configuration>
```

With file `connections.config` containing

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="name" connectionString="your conn_string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="name2" connectionString="your conn_string2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The "Add as Link" looks like a good concept. I'll try to test that out some but at the moment I'm not sure understand where you would put the configuration project. In other words, when I add the file as a shared link do I point it to a local file or to a file on the production server? Or, is the reference more virtual so I need to point to a file in a folder structure on my dev machine that mimics the production machine so that once it's published in prod it will look in the same location?

Comment: You just need to keep them in your local solution. You can either place them in a shared project (If already exists) or keep them as solution item. The physical location should be in the same solution hierarchy if you go with the second approach. Also the Build/Publish process should copy the configuration files to your build folder. In production it won't matter where those files were located in you solution.

Comment: I think this is going to work perfectly. I created a folder structure on both my dev machine and test server (d:\inetpub\config\connections.config). Then I did the Add as Link and pointed to that config file. I added the configSouce="connections.config" my config file like your posted code. Looks like that's going to work out. Now if something changes I just make the update in the d:\inetub\config\connections.config file on all the servers. Thanks for the code!

Comment: Just when I thought I was good with this I came across an issue. I was under the assumption that if we point to a shared file that it would look at the location of the shared file and pull the values from there. However it looks like all it's doing is copying in the share file into the project once you create it. So, lets say I do the shared file and then go add or make a change to one of the values. It's not reflecting that change in the code. It will have the old value and/or won't be able to find the new value.

Comment: Is there not a way to make the shared link always get a new copy of the shared file? If I need to make a change I don't want to have to go back and redo the shared link. I'm hoping to have one location for all the projects to look at in order to get the connection string. If a change is needed I just make the change on that one file and all the apps would pickup on that new change.

Comment: If you goto the properties of the `Linked` file you'll see options like `BuildAction`, `Copy to OutputDirectory`. Change `BuildAction` to `Content` and change `CopyToOutputDirectory` from `DoNotCopy` to `CopyIfNewer`.

Comment: Good deal. Looks like that might work. I had to delete the shared file and start over. I had initially changed the CopyToOuputDirectory to Copy Always but I didn't initially change the Build Action. I'll keep testing and if doesn't work I'll ask again but preliminary testing looks like that was the changed that was needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, I might be missing something but once I moved this off of my dev machine to my Test server it doesn't seem to work as expected. On my dev machine I can make a change to my connections.config file and every time I run the app in Debug mode it will pick up that change. I then created the same folder structure and moved the files to my Test server. This is a console app I just copied all of the files from my Project/Bin/Debug folder. This included the connections.config file that was in that bin directory. I put some code to log the values pulled from connections.config file.

Comment: I then went to my D:\inetpub\config file which is the folder structure of my shared link. I made a change to the config file to see if it would pick up the change. I did the same on my Dev machine and it worked. However on my test server it's still picking up the old settings. I'm assuming that the build process in Visual Studio will get the information from the shared link and copy it to projects debug folder. However, once it's built it will always look at that local connections.config file and from the shared link location. I was hoping it would always pull from the shared link.

Comment: No! Shared files are for development purpose only. Once the project is built they have their own copy in bin. For deployment you need to look for different solution.

Comment: Bummer! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class library JUST for this purpose, Add connection string as a property in a class file. Then you can always reference this library in any application that needs the connection string to the database.

Retrieve the connection string in code from the property value. However with this approach, if you make any changes you would always have to re-compile the code.

Comment: If I made this reference in say 20 applications then if something about the connection changed wouldn't I have to compile and redeploy all 20 apps? If that's the case then it kind of defeats my purpose of a central location. That wouldn't be any different than changing the App or Web config with the new changes on all 20 apps and then redeploying.